# Date Format Conversion in Java?

Tags: java, android

I have a date coming in JSON feeds in the format below:

```
 mm/dd/yyyy  for example today's date  10/26/2011
```

I want to convert it to another format, which is, infact a detailed date format as:

```
 Wed, 26 OCT 2011
```

How can i do that..??? I know this could be very simple, but am still a newbie, Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not very educational, but here's the solution ready to handle your request:

```
String dateString = "10/26/2011";
String dateStringParsed = "";
SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy");

try {
    Date parsed = format1.parse(dateString);
    dateStringParsed = format2.format(parsed);
}
catch(ParseException pe) { 
    //handle the exception
}
```

AFAIK, capitals in month are not available via SimpleDateFormat. You're gonna have to change it manually if it's necessary.

Comment: +1 for letting the OP handle the exception as he needs to, and providing correct patterns.

Comment: Thank you. It's nice to score some brownie points from the experienced user;)

Comment: @ Moyshe, i know it's not very educational but i got confused with formats. Thanks for your cooperation..!!!!

Comment: No problem - this is what this site is from. Although, take some time to look through the links given in other answers, they are very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example where I do exactly that in my android app.

```
public String GetJustTime(String input){
    SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date dateObj = new Date();
        try {
            dateObj = curFormater.parse(input);
        } catch (ParseException e) {}
        SimpleDateFormat postFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
        String newDateStr = postFormater.format(dateObj);

    return newDateStr;
}
```

Just change the 2 format string as appropriate for your needs.
The First one is for the incoming format, and the 2nd one is the format used for the output.

I beleive the output format you want is "EEE, d MMM YYYY", but I can't test it right now.

Comment: Are you aware that if the passed input is not a valid date according to the curFormater, then you'll just return the current date instead of the one passed as argument? This is a serious side-effect that, in most cases, is unwanted.

Comment: yep, that's the desired behavior in my application.  As I said it came right out of my code.  Thanks for mentioning it though, I appreciate it.

Comment: And your first pattern is wrong, because it uses minutes instead of months. And you don't respect Java naming conventions.

Comment: ok, that one could be a problem for me.. though I haven't seen any issues yet. thanks again. Going to look in to that first chance I get.

Comment: actually, I know why it hasn't surfaced yet...  I'm ignoring the date part entirely and only outputting the time, so it doesn't affect anything.  Fixing it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the solutions with SimpleDateFormat, just wanted to add an alternative solution with Joda's DateTimeFormatter (`org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`), which is generally considered a much better date/time API if you end up doing anything the least bit advanced with dates or times in your code. This solution can actually be all inlined into one line, but showing broken out here for clarity:

```
String source = "10/26/2011";
String target = "Wed, 26 Oct 2011";

DateTimeFormatter sourceFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
DateTimeFormatter targetFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("E, dd MMM yyyy");

assertEquals(target, sourceFormatter.parseDateTime(source).toString(targetFormatter));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) Class. One small example on how you can use this, taken from [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/378541/java/java/Convert-date-difference-format):

```
String dateString = new String("07/12/2005");
java.util.Date dtDate = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
SimpleDateFormat sdfAct = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
try
{
  dtDate = sdfAct.parse(dateString);
  System.out.println("Date After parsing in required format:"+(sdf.format(dtDate)));
}
catch (ParseException e)
{
  System.out.println("Unable to parse the date string");
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: The second format is wrong. It uses minutes instead of months. Your exception handling is awful.

Comment: I think he got his example from the same place I originally got mine :)  It looks very familiar.

Comment: I got the example from another website which I linked in my response. I did not write the code, I just wanted to point the OP in the right direction...